# Inconsistent information in DataGrid using List Concat c# wpf

Tags: c#, list, datagrid

I have one table called Registry, in a Registry class. 
It contains

- Number, Description, People_id

People_id is a foreign key from People table, in a People class.
It contains

- id, Name, birth_date

I need to show all the data from the Registry table in a DataGrid and the age for the People_id (calculated with the birth_date) in the Registry table. I already can retrieve all the Registry data and show it on the Datagrid but I'm missing the Age part.

I tried with something like this. Retrieve the Registry data, foreach to get Birth Dates, do the calculation and fill a List with only the Age result. Then, join the two List with the Concat method in a new List called CombRegistryAge as you can see below in the first method.

```
public List<object> RegistryJoinAge()
    {          
        List<object> ResultAge = new List<object>();
        List<Registry> ListRegistry = new Registry().LoadRegistry();
           //method LoadRegistry retrieve all items in Registry table
        foreach (var item in ListRegistry)
        {
           var age = AgeCalculation(item.People.birth_date);
            ResultAge.Add(age);
        }

        List<object> CombRegistryAge = ListRegistry.Cast<object>().Concat(ResultAge).ToList();
        return CombRegistryAge;
    }
```

For the AgeCalculation method, something simple to start testing

```
    private int AgeCalculation(DateTime birthdate)
    {
        var todayIs = DateTime.Today;
        int age = todayIs.Year - birthdate.Year;
        return age;
    }
```

But when I call the method using the List CombRegistryAge in the datagrid

```
datagrid_fillData.ItemsSource = RegistryJoinAge();
```

I still get the Registry data inside but not Age and I noticed, from the datagrid, it adds empty rows for every age calculated but in reality, I need them to be show as a single one, something like this in the datagrid.

- Id, Description, People_id, Age
- 101, Passed, 1802, 35

That's my doubt. Maybe it's a problem with the List because I tried reversing the list order in the concat method but it show and empty grid.
Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you create a class `UserRegistryModel`, to carry your data which can binding data in `datagrid`.

```
public class UserRegistryModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int People_id { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Use *Lambda*  `select` make the code more clear.

```
public List<UserRegistryModel> RegistryJoinAge()
{

    List<UserRegistryModel> ListRegistry = new Registry().LoadRegistry()
    .select(x => new UserRegistryModel()
    {
        Number = x.Number,
        Description = x.Description,
        People_id = x.People_id,
        Age = AgeCalculation(x.People.birth_date)
    }).ToList();

    return ListRegistry;
}
```

Final return `UserRegistryModel` List

Comment: Thank you so much! It was exactly what I needed. Marked as accepted answer!